# Am i missing a header to be able to upload to wistia?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, dotnet-httpclient, wistia

i'm trying to upload a video to wistia, but i'm not sure why im getting bad request or error code 500. i've been trying diferrent ways to upload the video.

```
            //Get file from the view;
            foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];
                fName = file.FileName;
                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    //add file to the request                        
                    formDataContent.Add(new StreamContent(file.InputStream),"file", fname);

                }
            }

            //get response from request
            responseMessage = await client.PostAsync(url, formDataContent);
            var result = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

also i've tried

```
client.BaseAddress = url;
HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Post, "?api_password=pass");
foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];
                fName = file.FileName;
                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    //add file to the request
                    formDataContent.Add(new StreamContent(file.InputStream),"file", fname);
                }
            }
req.Content = formDataContent;
 responseMessage = await client.SendAsync(req);
```

but none of these have worked, im getting the same error codes 400 & 500, hope you can help me with this problem. i don't have too much experience uploading files to a server.

Comment: Are there any error details you're receiving? 400 and 500 mean `bad request` and `internal server error`; we are not going to know what these mean in the case of your application. Surely there's an error message.

Comment: when i get error code 500, i get "NoMethodError at /
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
Ruby /opt/apps/bakery/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb: in method_override, line 26  
Web POST upload.wistia.com/ " and i think that's on their end since is code 500 and i think i shouldnt be able to see that.